# How to keep the direction of line unchanged in the recursion?

Tags: c#, recursion

With this function I want to draw a recursive tree but, when I call this function the direction of second line (which I want to draw recursively changes each time).

`a` Is the angle between `x` and the first line,

`b` Is the angle between first line and second line.

Photos: 
   [This is the First level recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn6yb.png)
   [This is the second level of recursion the problem is at highlighted line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwI5h.png) 
    How can I fix this problem?

```
public void drawTree(int n, float l, float x, float y, float a, float b, float c, 
                     float k1, float k2, float k3, float m2, float m3)
{
    //float k = (float)Math.Pow(-1, n+1);
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
    Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();

    float l1 = k1 * l;
    float l2 = k2 * l;
    float l3 = k3 * l;
    float g = m3 * l;
    float f = m2 * l;

    gr.DrawLine(p, x, y, x + l * cos(a), y - l * sin(a));
    if (n == 1) return;

    drawTree(n - 1, l2, x + f * cos(a), y - f * sin(a), (a - b), b, c, k1, k2, k3, m2, m3);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `l1`, `l2`, `l3`, and `g`? Can you explain all of the parameters being used?

Comment: l1, l2 and l3 are the childs, like the branch of trees but i only have used l2, g and f is the points on "l" where the l2, and l3 whill start

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see `g` being used anywhere.

Comment: As I said I only draw the l2, and as you see there is mistake therefore I dont draw l3 and g is not used. I have problems with sin and cos I think

Comment: it's likely the case, I'm trying to run it through in my head. What is the initial value of k2?

Comment: L = 150, k1 = 0.8F, k2 = 0.8F, k3 = 0.9F, a = -30.3f, b= 0.6F, c = 0.7F, m2 = 0.3F, m3 = 0.6F; this are the values bro  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you compute the new point, you're subtracting it from `y` which if sin(a) was positive, would be fine, but since it's not, it flips from being a negative subtraction to a positive subtraction.

If you iterate one level deeper, the next line should be drawn correctly.

Try either using a positive value `a` or 
`Math.Abs` the resulting `sin(a)`.

Comment: Now, I want to draw another line but, it draws only right side, it the problem of Math.Abs. because it does not care about the minus value of sin and cos

Comment: Are you calling Math.Abs on the x position too? You only want the absolute value for the y position.

Comment: Yes otherwise it becomes  <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztuCz.png"> like this </a>

Comment: You don't want to get the absolute value for `x` because that clamps it to one side like your problem. Rather, you need to the constrain the angle.